# Best way to store content?

Tags: java, android, sql, listview

First of all I want to thank you for even reading this. I'm a complete noob and I'm trying to learn Android Java. I've made many little "Learn Apps" in which I just try to learn things. Today I want to make another one.

I want to have ListView in the MainActivity which contains names of Food like:

1. Pizza
2. Ice Cream
3. Spaghetti
4. Apple
5. Orange
6. ...

When the user clicks on one of those a SecondActivity gets called and this SecondActivity contains a two TextViews. One with the name on which the user clicked and one with a description. Example:

User clicks on Pizza.

SecondActivity looks like this:

Pizza

Pizza is blah blah blah

and if the user clicks Orange:

Orange

Oranges are fruits blah blah blah

I hope you undestand me.

My question is now. Which is the easiest way to store this descriptions? An SQLDatabse? Or should I just write them like Strings and say. If user clicks this parse this String to TextView1 and this String to TextView2? I hope you understand me and can help me! Thank you very much!!

Comment: Store them in string-array

Comment: Depends on the life cycle of your content. If it only changes with software releases, use strings.

Comment: Even if the texts are very long? And then I say if user clicks pos 1 then take this text?

Comment: @blafasel yes it wont be changeable without new release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are static Strings (that you may or may not want to translate later on) you would probably be best saving them as a String array in a `resource.xml` file:
(The filename can be *anything_you_like*.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="food_names">
        <item>apple</item>
        <item>orange</item>
        <item>pizza</item>
        <item>blah</item>
        <item>blah</item>
    </string-array>
    <string-array name="food_descriptions">
        <item>green, doctor friendly</item>
        <item>round, hurts eyes</item>
        <item>flat, cheezy, liked by turtles</item>
        <item>blah</item>
        <item>blah</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

You need to locate the file inside your `values` folder and you then get the option to do all the fancy folder variations like `values-v14`, `values-v16` and `values-en`, `values-es`, `values-fr` and so on, and so on...

You can later access this `String[]` from your code to grab the appropriate version for the user's API and language with:

```
String[] foodNames = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_names);
String[] foodDescriptions = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.food_descriptions);

static final String FOOD_FORMAT = "%s :: $s";
for (int i=0; i<foodNames.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(
            String.format(FOOD_FORMAT,
                          foodNames[i],
                          foodDescriptions[i]
            )
    );
}
```

Comment: should I create this resource file in the values directory?

Comment: You can create your arrays on string.xml file or a new file called arrays.xml

Comment: @r0d, added that info to my answer. The folder name matters, the filename does not. As long as it's an XML file the name can be anything.

Comment: @indivisible perfect thank you. Going to write some weird stuff now and later find out how to say if user clicks this take this. THANK YOU

Comment: shouldn't I make the descriptions in normal strings so I can say if user clicks orange put string orange_despription into textview 2 in second activity

Comment: you could but then you will have to map a selection index (integer) to a food (String) to a description (resource). Using Arrays like above you can just get the selected index of the selected food pass just that everywhere. Grab the same index from the descriptions and they will already match. It's easy to put an int in an intent or Bundle to pass between Activities or Fragments and the array will always be the same. Just make sure you always keep the pairings paired and it's easy-peasy. And since the Arrays are defined in xml resources you still get the easy localisation later if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

indivisible's answer is acceptable to your case. But considering that your content may change and may be more detailed, you should stick to an SQLite database. You only will need a simple table insert your data. Having an if else chain is not the cleanest way and definitely is not friendly when you think about scalability. But if you really want to use the second approach, use a switch, instead of an if else chain.

If in the future, you want to add other elements to your data, just change your database as you like and that is it.

Comment: Well thank you for that. My problem is I really have trouble understanding SQLDatabases and I tried many tutorials but I really don't get it. Someday when I know how to do it I may change it! Thank you too!

Comment: @r0d, The best way to deal with them (databases) is with multiple layers of abstraction. Each layer does its part and you end up with a few methods that you can call to do some fairly complicated, magical things. When you're ready to try to tackle it [this is the tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html) I usually point people to